# How do I change the react router path from /#/homepage to /app/#/homepage

Tags: reactjs, react-router

We are using Node.js server and React Router. We have SSO rules that will require us to change our URL pattern. I am trying to adjust the default paths from this pattern:

mysite.com/#/homepage

to:

mysite.com/app/#/homepage

I believe by default the hash is handled directly after the domain, but as you can see we are trying to prepend it with 'app' instead. How can this be done? We are currently using React Router like so:

```
<Route name="app" path="/" handler={App}>
  <Redirect from="/" to="homepage" />
  <Route path="homepage" name="home" handler={MyContent} />
</Route>
```

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Comment: My coworker found a workaround. I discovered that we are using both Express Router and React Router. Apparently the React Router only recognizes everything after the hash (#) in the url. So the solution was really more of an adjustment to the Express Router

Answer (score 1):

Host your app itself/serve your app on `/app`. Either via some kind of DNS, etc. depending on your server structure.

Answer (score 0):

With a hash approach you CAN NOT. It's like you want to do something like this :

`mysite.com/homepage` -> `mysite.net/homepage`

Because client can just see the part of URL next to `#`.

So you may consider handling your routes using [server-side](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ServerRendering.md) approach.

It give you more power and flexiblity than the `#` approach.

Comment: So if I am understanding, you are suggesting that this should be done on the server side rather than React Router. Does this sound right? If so, are you aware of a way to accomplish this with Node.js Express?

Comment: @jbambrough You can handle routes on server side using React-Router
If you are using RR v4 you can follow the instruction given in [this link](https://react-router.now.sh/ServerRouter)

If RR v3 then [this](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ServerRendering.md)